# Why Facebook token is different in signed_request and in app settings?

Tags: facebook

The new Developer application shows an access token on app settings page. It is different from the token Facebook sends to the application in **signed_request** and the one I can get from https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token.

The problem is that the token from the app settings page seems to be the "correct" one (I can do **fql.multiquery** with it) and the one from **signed_request**/oauth is not (calling **fql.multiquery** with it returns error # 15: "*The method you are calling must be called with an app secret signed session*").

Could you please explain what is going on?
And how do get this "correct" token?

Comment: fql.multiquery failed because I used standard_user_info table. When I used the table "user", everything was OK, even with the token given to me by Facebook in signed_request.

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of OAuth tokens:

- A user access token - used to query information about that user (e.g. their friends, posts, events etc.)
- An app access token - used for application-level queries such as realtime updates, stats

The token sent with signed request is the first type - it's the token for the currently logged in user, which you can use to query Facebook. The error message you are receiving indicates that the operation you are trying to run needs a token of the second type.

See more info in the Auth docs: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ . On that page, the section "User Login" relates to the first type and the section "App Login" relates to the second.

Comment: Thank you. I got the application token of course too. It is shorter than the "regular" token and is absolutely different from the one displayed on the app settings page. When I attach it to the fql.multiquery request, Facebook says it is either invalid or expired. The latter is not true because I've just received it, in the same script. I still have no idea how to get the token displayed on the app settings page.